# Wireshark with Libpcap (or WinPcap) portable (without Admin rights

Tags: wireshark, portability, libpcap

The portable version of wireshark from:
https://www.wireshark.org/download.html
works fine on my windows 10, but doesn't include portable capturing triber Libpcap or WinPcap.

On the Npcap page
https://nmap.org/npcap/
it is written:
"Libpcap API: Npcap uses the excellent Libpcap library, **enabling Windows applications to use a portable packet capturing API** and so indeed on the Libpcap library page
https://www.tcpdump.org/
there is the portable C/C++ **Libpcap** library available.

How can I use the C/C++ **Libpcap** library within Wireshark or with Java (pcap4j)?
I downloaded it and it consists mainly of *.h files.

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I use the C/C++ Libpcap library within Wireshark

If you're on a UN*X, libpcap is usually shipped as part of the operating system, so it should Just Work.

If you're on Windows, you need a version of libpcap that's made to work on Windows.  That's what Npcap is.

If you want to capture traffic on Windows, you will have to install Npcap; you can't just run a Wireshark from a flash drive or other medium containing a [portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application) version of Wireshark without installing anything, you will *have* to install Npcap on your computer.

> I downloaded it and it consists mainly of *.h files.

You downloaded the source code, which isn't directly usable.  It has to be compiled - and installed.

Comment: Thans!   "You downloaded the source code, which isn't directly usable. It has to be compiled - and installed."      Would I be able after compiling to install it without admin rights?

Comment: "Would I be able after compiling to install it without admin rights?" Probably not.  Arbitrary accounts being able to install drivers is generally not considered safe, so Microsoft probably doesn't allow it.